# Logging python module in two separate files

Tags: python

I have three files in three different modules: `a/foo.py, b/bar.py, and c/foobar.py`. Each are configured using `logger.getLogger(__name__)`. `foo.py` is configured under the `a` module, and `bar.py` under the `b` module. However, `c/foobar.py` is used by both `foo.py` and `bar.py`, and I would like the logs from `foobar.py` to be inserted into the `a` or `b` logfiles, depending on which file called it.

How is this accomplished?

Comment: Please show us your code.  Generally, you would add two FileHandler's or one if it's descendants, one for a.log and one for b.log, however until we see your code we can't tell you exactly how to go about doing that.

Comment: instead of getting a logger by itself, you can pass a logger instance to `c/foobar.py` from the callers (either a or b in your case)